# How to change the form border color c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, border

I would like to change window form border color (the border with the form title). The example I found in [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=CustomerBorderForm) is too much and confusing. Can any help me on something simpler?

Answer (score 19):

Override it with:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle, Color.[your_color], ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}
```

Comment: color from rgb example:
System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 106, 181)

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, since the form border is drawn by the Operating System, this **is a complicated task**.  There is no real way around that.

> Do NOT click the ProjectDistributor link on the CodePlex page below

The [CodePlex Project for Drawing Custom Borders](http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/) makes this very easy, though.  Just build the form using SkinnedForm from that project instead of a standard Form, and it should work - you really don't need to do anything different in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Reed... even with soure cod from codeplex im still having problem to change the top border colour or rather all the border colour.

Comment: The link does not exist, nor does codeplex.com lead anywhere.

Answer (score 10):

## Workaround - Just follow these steps:

- Set `FormBorderStyle` to `None`.
- Cover the form with a panel and leave some space for border.
- Set the color you want for the border as the form back color.

Now, the panel serves as the main container and you can change the background as you want and the form serves as the border.

#### The Final Result

[image]

For dragging the window around see this post:
[Make a borderless form movable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/make-a-borderless-form-movable)

Comment: Exactly, It`s best solution but unfortunately with a lot of troubles... Such as add ability to Move that panel, add Resizing to form and etc.

Comment: @MiMFa, the answer is now updated to include a hint of how to make a borderless form movable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Windows 10 and 11:

```
    private string ToBgr(Color c) => $"{c.B:X2}{c.G:X2}{c.R:X2}";

    [DllImport("DwmApi")]
    private static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, int[] attrValue, int attrSize);

    const int DWWMA_CAPTION_COLOR = 35;
    const int DWWMA_BORDER_COLOR = 34;
    const int DWMWA_TEXT_COLOR = 36;
    public void CustomWindow(Color captionColor, Color fontColor, Color borderColor, IntPtr handle)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = handle;
        //Change caption color
        int[] caption = new int[] { int.Parse(ToBgr(captionColor), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) };
        DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWWMA_CAPTION_COLOR, caption, 4);
        //Change font color
        int[] font = new int[] { int.Parse(ToBgr(fontColor), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) };
        DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWA_TEXT_COLOR, font, 4);
        //Change border color
        int[] border = new int[] { int.Parse(ToBgr(borderColor), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) };
        DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWWMA_BORDER_COLOR, border, 4);

    }
```

Example:

```
CustomWindow(Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Handle);
```

Comment: That changes the caption color. Did you mean to use `DWMWA_BORDER_COLOR` instead?

Comment: Yes I did, I just edited my post. Thank you.

Comment: Still pretty inefficient to go from a [`System::Drawing::Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color), turn that into a string, only to parse that string into the numeric values of the individual channel components you had right from the get-go. Why not just use those numbers available through the `A`, `R`, `G`, and `B` properties as-is?

Comment: You are right, but the color has to be BGR and not RGB / ARGB, so I can't use the color as it is.

Comment: You can still construct an array out of the `A`, `R`, `G`, `B` values, swizzling them as needed, without going through a string, with allocations and all.

Comment: I don't know much about parsing values, but the BGR color is in hex code, would that still be possible?

Comment: No, they are not in *"hex code"*. They are values, ready to be used. No parsing involved. You'll just have to understand that a `String` isn't the only data type there is.

Comment: Don't worry, I know there are more data types than `String`, I posted the code because it worked well for me in my projects, so I wanted to share it (even though the color string is a bit complicated).

Comment: It works, but certainly doesn't *"work well"*. I mean, here's a number, let's turn that number into a string, now let's split up that string, and parse out the individual substrings into numbers, only to put them back into another number. Like, what's wrong with `new byte[] { 0, col.B, col.G, col.R };`? Not that I know .NET or C#, but that's probably just going to compile down to a handful of CPU instructions, rather than hundreds, as your suggestion would.

Comment: There is nothing wrong `new byte[] { 0, col.B, col.G, col.R };` is a really good method, i just didnt know any other methods than the color string.

Comment: I can't verify whether it compiles or works, as I don't know C# nor have a .NET dev environment readily available. Though if that works for you, update your proposed answer (after having verified that it works). I just know that reordering bytes is far more efficient, and far less subject to fail (there's literally no way for that to even fail).

Answer (score 0):

Use my project to create custom form: [RemasterForms](https://github.com/coderemaster/RemasterForms)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34526855)

Answer (score -1):

Like previously mentioned, changing the actual color of the border is difficult. The solution above with the panel has limitations like you can't resize the form. I found a reasonably easy trick without a lot of the other limitations.

- Create a form
- Set FormBorderStyle to None
- Add 4 panels
- Set the background color of the panels to the color of the border you want
- Anchor one each to the top, bottom, left, and right
- Set the height(top/bottom) or width (left/right) to the thickness of the border you want. 2 or 3 looks really good.

It looks like a border, it will resize with the window, and you can drop anything else into the form you want. The limitation is, you must do this as the very first thing you add to the form.

Answer (score -2):

Below "ForeColor" their should be a setting called "FormBorderStyle" You can edit it with that in VisualStudio 2015. Or you can go in control panel path should be something like this "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization"
their will be a second setting called "Color" can change that to be what color you want it will change the color of the boarder in all of the programs to the color you set.

Comment: I think this user is asking how to do this task through code.

Answer (score -8):

```
if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string color = Convert.ToString(colorDialog1.Color);
    MessageBox.Show("You change the color " + color);
    this.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color; // BackColor is only accessible for this form
}
```

Comment: The question was about border color, not background color.