# Drag borderless windows form by mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, drag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Make a borderless form movable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/c-sharp-make-a-borderless-form-movable)

I have made a form without border in C#, by setting

`this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;`

Now, problem is how can I drag it by mouse?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for ["Enhanced: Drag and move WinForms"](http://jachman.wordpress.com/2006/06/08/enhanced-drag-and-move-winforms-without-having-a-titlebar/)

```
public partial class MyDraggableForm : Form
{
    private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    private const int HTCLIENT = 0x1;
    private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;

    ///
    /// Handling the window messages
    ///
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref message);

        if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && (int)message.Result == HTCLIENT)
            message.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
    }
    public MyDraggableForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

As the blog post states, this is a way to "fool" the system. This way you don't need to think about mouse up/down events.

Comment: Keep in mind that as a side effect the window will maximize window on double click. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1592899/855432) does not cause this problem.

Comment: Can I make it draggable on certain portion only? eg withing a control region

Comment: It also kills the right mouse button.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a horrible solution. It kills right-click, double-clicking anywhere on the form maximizes it... It's already more trouble than it's worth - could've already implemented mouseDown/mouseUp and mouseMove events by the time you finish fixing the maximize and right-click-killer issues.

Comment: FYI, link in answer is dead - *"jachman.wordpress.com is no longer available. The authors have deleted this site."*

Answer (score 2):

You have to register for the MouseDown, MouseUp and MouseMove events and move the form according to the movement of the mouse.

Comment: This answer would be more valuable with a code example. The math for moving the form based on mouse coordinates is not trivial.