# Add drag behavior to a form with FormBorderStyle set to None

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Make a borderless form movable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/c-sharp-make-a-borderless-form-movable)

If I set my form's `FormBorderStyle` to `None`, I lose the drag behavior of the form, as expected.

I've added a custom bar to the top of my form and I like it to stay that way, now is it possible to keep the form in this mode and have (or write) drag behavior?

If it's possible, how should I do so. I really hope to find a **Yes it's possible answer.** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private const Int32 WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
private const Int32 HTCLIENT = 0x1;
private const Int32 HTCAPTION = 0x2;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if ((Int32)m.Result == HTCLIENT)
            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;

        return;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Worths to mantion that this solution treats like a TitleBar entire form surface, so making double click on any part of the form will make it maximize, so it has to be handled too.

Comment: I suppose that these magic numbers refers to NC_HITTEST message as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767831/drag-borderless-windows-form-by-mouse?rq=1) , but this is not exactly  what the OP asked

Comment: @Zarathos: I just edited by adding constants to your code.

Comment: The OP asked for a draggable form with FormBorderStyle.None. And here is how to do it.