# How can I make my simple Windows Form button "click and draggable"?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple widget I'm building, a button that does something when you click it, and something else when you click it again.

I plan on hiding the border via `this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;`, but when I do this, I lose the ability to move the window around.

How do I allow my button to be moved when the mouse button is held down, and the button to be activated when the mouse button is clicked?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/make-a-borderless-form-movable, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767831/drag-borderless-windows-form-by-mouse, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184/winforms-click-drag-anywhere-in-the-form-to-move-it-as-if-clicked-in-the-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private Point MouseDownLocation;


    private void btn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void btn_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            btn.Left = e.X + btn.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
            btn.Top = e.Y + btn.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hah, nice a simple. I like it! Thank's a bunch.

Comment: Any easy way to stop the button from being "clicked" if the window moved before `mouseup`?

Comment: Alternatively you have to use "CTRL+MOUSE_DOWN" or "SHIFT+MOUSE_DOWN", when release either Keyboard button or mouse button it will stop dragging.