# How to put the Cursor on Form Move mode

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I am creating a form which has no borders, but I want the user to be able to move it on clicking a button (the form is not locked).

How could I do it C#?

This is the "Move" I am talking about :

[image: Move]

Comment: You can find your answer on this link[ Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/c-sharp-make-a-borderless-form-movable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is "to say" to Windows that all form is a CAPTION.

- good: it's easy and works as you cheat OS, so it behaves blindly.
- bad: consider, for example, that making a double-click on your window will lead to maximize.

Other way is: track ouse down point, and mousemove and move your form accordingly.

All possible examples can find on post searching for:

*Winforms - Click/drag anywhere in the form to move it as if clicked in the form caption*, 
or following link provided in comments.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to call Win API [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

```
SendMessage(SYS_COMMAND, SC_MOVE);
```

Comment: I did what Tigran said and it worked just fine :)