# How to make a picturebox dragable?

Tags: c#, winforms, operating-system

I am an enthusiastic programmer and new to stack overflow.
I am trying to build a prototype of an OS(Operating System) in C#...Just a test.

Just like we see that we can drag things in the desktop and put it anywhere I am creating a desktop for my OS.

So how should I make an icon(a picturebox) drag-able and how would I save its position so that next time I open my desktop I see it in the same place?
I would love the dragging without any freezes or those sneaky bugs. I would love if, it is as close and smooth as the ones in Windows(dragging items(icons) in desktop)..

Thanks...

Comment: wpf? winforms? perhaps web?

Comment: C#, winforms bro..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Assume a Picturebox named "pbxBigCat" (load it with a pPicture ...)

Add this lines to your form:

```
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
```

And then write an eventhandler for the pbxBigCat MouseDown event:

```
    private void pbxBigCat_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(pbxBigCat.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }
```

If you test it you will se it works. For more Information (like saving positions etc.) I refere to [Make a borderless form movable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/make-a-borderless-form-movable)

**Another possibility to do this (now we have a Label called label1)**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool mouseDown;
    private Point lastLocation;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pbxBigCat_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mouseDown = true;
            lastLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void pbxBigCat_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseDown)
        {
            pbxBigCat.Location = new Point((pbxBigCat.Location.X - lastLocation.X + e.X), (pbxBigCat.Location.Y - lastLocation.Y) + e.Y);
            label1.Text = pbxBigCat.Location.X.ToString() + "/" + pbxBigCat.Location.Y.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void pbxBigCat_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = false;
    }
}
```

Everything drawn from the example on the mentioned SO article.

Comment: I thought the code would work perfectly but nothing really happens and I even tried it on a form and the referral link you gave me contains no information on how to save the positions.

Comment: Then you did not read the full thread. You can use the mousemove event to get the actual positions, and then save it for your purposes.

Comment: And i tried it again, and it is operating. I can move around the picture.

Comment: see the new, alternate method for your request.

Comment: Thanks bro. The alternative method is working really nicely. You are the best. Thanks a very lot.

Comment: You are welcome ... If this answer fits your needs, please ACCEPT it as answer - thats the way to say thanks!