# Windows forms move form from any panel (with border set to none)

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, windows-forms-designer

I set the border in the form to null/none so now I can't move the form.. So I found this code which is not firring because my whole form is made of panels:

```
    private bool dragging = false;
    private Point dragCursorPoint;
    private Point dragFormPoint;

    private void HomeScreen_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragging = true;
        dragCursorPoint = Cursor.Position;
        dragFormPoint = this.Location;
    }

    private void HomeScreen_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragging)
        {
            Point dif = Point.Subtract(Cursor.Position, new Size(dragCursorPoint));
            this.Location = Point.Add(dragFormPoint, new Size(dif));
        }
    }

    private void HomeScreen_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragging = false;
    }
```

HomeScreen Form Mouse Event are not firring because the Form is filled with panels. So somehow I should link the panel clicks to the form clicks (mouse event). Is there a way to do that so I can move my form from wherever I want too?

Comment: Use exact code of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1592899/3110834) and handle `MouseDown` event of all panels using the same method in the answer.

Comment: Well, just use one more panel.  Dock it to the top, make it about 30 pixels tall, give it a distinct color.  You can draw a description of the window, perhaps draw an X.  And now both you and your user will know how to move the window.

Comment: Did that, works, sorry for duplicate