# Add System Default Context Menu to Borderless Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, contextmenu

I removed the default Border from my Windows Form and created my own header which i want to give the same features as the default windows one.

One of them is the context Menu that is displayed on Right Mouse Click:

[image: Default Context Menu]

Is there a possibility to assign this to my costum header?

If you want to post code I would prefer vb, but c# is also okay.

Comment: What did you try, other than move, the code for the other options is ridiculously simple, so what did you try?

Comment: @BugFinder I dont want to recreate the context menu, I want to somehow call the System Default one

Comment: @VisualVincent It was falsely marked as duplicate because my question was about Windows Form and the other one about WPFs

Comment: @VisualVincent Closing that question as duplicate seems to be my fault. While the linked post is really useful to solve the problem, but a border-less form doesn't have system menu by default. You should first enable system menu for the form by adding WS_SYSMENU style in CreateParams. Then you can send WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU to the window in OnMouseDown

Comment: I tryd the solution is the "duplicate question" and it was not working for me, because some class was not available in Windows Forms

Comment: @VisualVincent Thank you. Those APIs are completely useful, the main difference is not having SystemMenu by default in a borderless WinForms `Form`. First you should enable the system menu in the way that I shared in this answer, then you can use `TrackPopupMenu` and so on or use a `WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU` as I did.

Comment: I did make those changes but it still didnt worked, I just didnt remerbered that as I wrote my comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A border-less form doesn't have system menu by default. You should first enable system menu for the form by adding [`WS_SYSMENU`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles?WT.mc_id=5003235) style in [`CreateParams`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.createparams?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8). Then you can send `WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU` to the window in [`OnMouseDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onmousedown?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8).

**C#**

Set `this.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;` then:

```cs
private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
private const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;
private const int WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x10000;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams p = base.CreateParams;
        p.Style = WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
        return p;
    }
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg,
    IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
private const int WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU = 0x313;
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var p = MousePosition.X + (MousePosition.Y * 0x10000);
        SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)p);
    }
}
```

**VB.NET**

Set `Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None` then:

```vb
Private Const WS_SYSMENU As Integer = &H80000
Private Const WS_MINIMIZEBOX As Integer = &H20000
Private Const WS_MAXIMIZEBOX As Integer = &H10000
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Dim p = MyBase.CreateParams
        p.Style = WS_SYSMENU + WS_MINIMIZEBOX + WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
        Return p
    End Get
End Property

<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, _
    ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
Private Const WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU As Integer = &H313
Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        Dim p = MousePosition.X + (MousePosition.Y * &H10000)
        SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU, 0, p)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note**

`WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU` is undocumented but completely working. If you want to use a documented way you can get the system menu using [`GetSystemMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmenu?WT.mc_id=5003235) and then show it using [`TrackPopupMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenu?WT.mc_id=5003235) and using a [`SendMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage?WT.mc_id=5003235) execute returned command., you can declare:

```vb
Private Const TPM_LEFTBUTTON As Integer = &H0
Private Const TPM_RIGHTBUTTON As Integer = &H2
Private Const TPM_RETURNCMD As Integer = &H100
Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetSystemMenu(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
    ByVal bRevert As Boolean) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function TrackPopupMenu(ByVal hMenu As IntPtr, ByVal uFlags As Integer, _
    ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal nReserved As Integer, _
    ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal prcRect As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, _
    ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

And show the menu this way:

```vb
Dim menu = GetSystemMenu(Me.Handle, False)
Dim command = TrackPopupMenu(menu, TPM_RETURNCMD + TPM_LEFTBUTTON + TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, _
                    MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, IntPtr.Zero, _
                    Me.Handle, IntPtr.Zero)
If (command > 0) Then
    SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, command, IntPtr.Zero)
End If
```

Comment: almost working perfectly - Move Option and Positioning of the Menu do not work

Comment: It's the way that it works. Move needs title-bar. Or you can alternatively use solutions which are available for moving borderless forms.

Comment: What do I have to change for the Positioning Part and how can I make the Moce Option work(I got the Code for Moving, but how to implement it)

Comment: Take a look at [this pot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1592899/3110834). Converting it to VB.NET is really simple. You have`SendMessage` in this answer, also here is `ReleaseCapture`: `<DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function ReleaseCapture() As Boolean`

Comment: I needed to amend the vb example for createparams as p.Style = p.Style Or WS_SYSMENU ...   for although the example worked at runtime it was breaking my forms designer.