# c# add a click event to a borderless draggable form

Tags: c#, winforms

I've made a circle shaped movable form using the code in the following link
[Make a borderless form movable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/make-a-borderless-form-movable)

this Code:

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{     
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}
```

Now my form is moving as I wanted but I want to add a click event to that form, but click event isn't firing. Can anyone tell what I'm missing?

Note: I just want to call a function whenever someone clicks my form.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Hard to know what you are missing when we don't even know what you have...

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: You probably don't need the click event.  What code are you trying to run?

Comment: I have made my form movable by this code and now I'm trying to call a function whenever someone click that form. But that click event isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MouseMove method instead of the MouseDown method:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
  base.OnMouseMove(e);

  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    ReleaseCapture();
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
  }
}

protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnClick(e);
  MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
}
```

A form does not have to listen to their own events, so I am just overriding the  MouseMove and Click procedures in the code above.

Comment: but this code will execute even when the user only tries to re-position the form. isn't it?

Comment: @AshfaqAfzal Updated the answer.