# How to have an OnClick event after enabling mobility of borderless form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, click, drag

I have a borderless form that I want to be movable. I have used [@Joey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/make-a-borderless-form-movable) In order to do that. but after I did it I have noticed that my `Click` event is no longer activated when my form `Form1` is clicked. How can I have both the functionality of the mobile borderless form **and** the ability to activate the function `form1_Click()` onclick?

Comment: If you say (with SendMessage) that the MouseDown (`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`) is on the Caption (`HT_CAPTION`), or in a `WM_NCHITTEST` (WndProc) you return `IntPtr(2)` = `HTCAPTION`, then the mouse events are no longer directed to your Form. You can use one of the other answers, using the MouseDown and MouseMove events. BTW, you don't need to PInvoke `ReleaseCapture()`, can set `this.Capture = false;`, same thing.

Comment: @Jimi is jay_t55 answer's valid?

Comment: Yes, it's one of the possible ways. I assume you want to move your Form clicking anywhere on it, so you don't have a *fake* title bar.

Comment: @Jimi If I want a specific location in the form to be clicked in order to move it (and all the rest will not have that functionality), is that possible? I know it is not part of the question but just I tried to do it and it didn't work out

Comment: Of course. You can use another control (a Label, for example) and handle the `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` events of this control. Or you can define an area, as a Rectangle, and determine whether the current mouse position is included in this area using the [Rectangle.Contains(Point)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.contains) method.