# put a panel out of the winform and make it moveable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel, windows-forms-designer

With the following code i am able to move a panel inside my Windows-Form during run time.

```
    Private position As New Point()
    Private Sub Pnl_Osc_Settings_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Pnl_Osc_Settings.MouseMove

        Dim p As Panel = CType(Pnl_Osc_Settings, Panel)

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then

            Dim mousePos As Point = Me.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)

            If position.IsEmpty = True Then
                position = New Point(mousePos.X - p.Left, mousePos.Y - p.Top)
            End If
            p.Location = New Point(mousePos.X - position.X, mousePos.Y - position.Y)

        ElseIf Not position.IsEmpty = True Then

            position = New Point()

        End If


    End Sub
```

Is there an option to move this panel outside of my windows form?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No, panels cannot be top-level windows. Use a borderless Form, and see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/make-a-borderless-form-movable

Comment: No there isn't. You would have to create a separate form and put the `Panel` on that. You can then display that form in the current one, over it or outside it.

Answer (score 1):

impossible.
However, if you use System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc , you will be able to pass controls to other forms you create.

Comment: The purpose of Ipc is transporting messages between remote points as basic data types and not UI. UI’s needs a direct rendering by a top level window and cannot be transported by Ipc. In your shoes I’ll remove the answer :)

Comment: I may misunderstand the question.
But. I can make a control as data and pass it to another form using ipc. It's unnecessary work. :)