# How to paint borders of Windows form in C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, border-layout

How to show our Winforms as MetroUI .. Without using 3rd party dll... I mean How to paint the borders of form

```
      [Form1_______________-|[]|X] <- I Can able to change the color of this part
     |                          |
     |                          |<- I cant change the color of this part
    -|                          |
    ||__________________________|
    |          |-> I cant change the color of this part
    V
    I cant change the color of this part
```

---

I dont this ..but it gives static color i want to change the color...so pls give me ideas in this

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, 0, 0));


    }
    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
    (
        int nLeftRect, // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
        int nTopRect, // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
        int nRightRect, // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
        int nBottomRect, // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
        int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
        int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
     );
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162743(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the form border color c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445472/how-to-change-the-form-border-color-c)

Comment: I dont want to use 3rd party dll i mentioned it...possible duplicate u r saying is done by 3rd party dll... so @Reniuz Read the part fully and comment

Comment: I read everything and understand clearly. If you didin't know you can download sources from codeplex and [here](http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6125) is sources of that 3rd party dll, which you can use. And [links](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/articles/CustomBorderForms.aspx) to blog where is explained everything. So **you** should read everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the form border color c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445472/how-to-change-the-form-border-color-c)