# How to change border colour and thicknesses in visual studio vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a label on my form which I'm wanting to have a thick white border.
At the moment i have selected a border style from properties but I can't edit it.

Is there a way I can change this?

I'm guessing I can hard code it in the designer bit but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: The inbuilt border options are limited. Instead, set the `BackColor` to one colour and handle the `Paint` event to draw the other. You can call `DrawRectangle` to draw the border or call `FillRectangle` to draw the part inside the border.

Comment: You can build a Custom Control derived from Label, override `CreateParams` and set `[params].ExStyle = [params].ExStyle Or &H200`. This adds a thick frame to the Control (it extends the Single and Fixed3D border styles generated by the BorderStyle property, you can paint over it). Unless you want a *special* custom border, then you have to paint it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try the following method:

1. Set `FormBorderStyle` to None
2. Cover the form with a panel and leave some space for border
3. Set the color you want for the border as the form back color

Use the panel serves as the main container,then you can change the background and the form serves as the border. You can also refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445472/how-to-change-the-form-border-color-c).